# Is there any quantum annealer simulator offered by DWave?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, simulation, d-wave, annealing

I am searching for quantum annealer simulator offered by DWave. I found classical solvers in dimod packages that implement simulated annealing, but I couldn’t find solver that simulates the real quantum annealer.

Please let me know wheter there is any simulator offered by DWave.

Comment: +1 and welcome to the community! However, why does the simulator need by be offered by D-Wave?

Answer (score 2):

> "I found classical solvers in dimod packages that implement simulated annealing, but I couldn’t find solver that simulates the real quantum annealer."

"Simulated annealing" is the closest you're going to get from D-Wave to "simulating quantum annealing".

A [quantum Monte Carlo](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1594/5) code can also simulate quantum annealing, and with computational scaling that is more similar to D-Wave's quantum annealing than "simulated annealing" is. This is depicted below:

[image]

However, the QMC calculations were done by Google, not D-Wave.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for the figure

Comment: @MonteNero https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.031015 To save time I copied and pasted it from https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/103953/59140 (which did have the original reference). In the future I'll try to be better with citations.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Julia package called [QuantumAnnealing.jl](https://github.com/lanl-ansi/QuantumAnnealing.jl) that simulates quantum annealing - it is specifically not just running simulated annealing as emulation of Quantum Annealing. This package was not developed by D-Wave.

Importantly, this package can be quite computationally intensive for large problem sizes, but it will let you investigate small problem sizes. You can specify different annealing schedules as well. One thing that is important though is that this package does not simulate noise directly; it is numerically simulating an ideal computation, and there are a couple ways that you can add in some effective noise into the computation.

Here are the direct links to the [documentation](https://lanl-ansi.github.io/QuantumAnnealing.jl/stable/) and a [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJnw2AnT-nI) about the package.